# Can't replace a file after comparing with a second one awk

Tags: regex, awk, text-processing

I am trying to compare two files and then replace the content of the first file with its matching content from the second file.

First file:

```
14523 : NOT
98765 : OTH
23145 : UNT
65743 : NOT
```

Second file:

```
23145vec#1
14523vec#2
65743vec#3
98765vec#4
```

The output should be like:

```
23145vec#1 : UNT
14523vec#2 : NOT
65743vec#3 : NOT
98765vec#4 : OTH
```

What I tried to do was:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { F2[$1] = $1 } ($1 in F2){print F2[$1] = $1" : "$2; next} ' file2 file1 > final.txt
```

The result :

```
23145vec#1 :
14523vec#2 :
65743vec#3 :
98765vec#4 :
```

Comment: the keys to be compared `14523` , `98765`, etc.. are they always five characters?

Comment: Yes, the key will always be formed by 5 characters.

Comment: None of the answers are trying to explain why your original attempt didn't work - When you did `$1 in F2`, it would mean an "identical" match of element `$1` with one of the indices in `F2`, but it is not the case with your given input. Lines in the second file only contain "part" of the lines in first file. So you would need to apply some regex match condition to match the elements

Answer (score 5):

As the key is numeric, you can truncate the non-numeric part off by adding a zero to it, ie. `"23145vec#1"+0=23145`:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1]=$3
    next
}
(k=($1+0)) in a {
    printf "%s : %s\n",$1,a[k]
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
23145vec#1 : UNT
14523vec#2 : NOT
65743vec#3 : NOT
98765vec#4 : OTH
```

Comment: nice, this is better than `substr($0,1,5)` solution I was going to suggest

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=" : "
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$NF
  next
}
match($0,/^[0-9]*/) && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) in a{
  print $0,a[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                          ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                                         ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=" : "                                                 ##Setting field and output field separator as " : " for all lines.
}
FNR==NR{                                                       ##Checking FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file1 is being read.
  a[$1]=$NF                                                    ##Creating array a with index $1 and value of last field here.
  next                                                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
match($0,/^[0-9]*/) && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) in a{         ##Using match function of awk to match digits from starting till anything else comes and checking if that matched regex substring is present in array a then do following.
  print $0,a[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]                        ##Printing current line and value of array a with matched regex sub string here.
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2                                    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** If Input_file2 has always 5 initial characters matched with Input_file1 then try following please.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=" : "
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$NF
  next
}
substr($0,1,5) in a{
  print $0,a[substr($0,1,5)]
}
'  file1  file2
```

***Why OP's attempt didn't work:*** Since field separator is NOT set properly for Input_file1 and Input_file2 hence OP's attempt is not working. IMHO setting 2 different field separator will be difficult process so I advice for above 2 solutions, will try to add OP's attempt correction once I get time too :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative `awk`:

```
awk -F '[ \t]*:[ \t]*' 'NR == FNR {
   map[$1] = $2
   next
}
$1 in map {
   print $0, ":", map[$1]
}' file1 FS='vec#' file2
```

'

```
23145vec#1 : UNT
14523vec#2 : NOT
65743vec#3 : NOT
98765vec#4 : OTH
```

`FS='vec#'` before `file2` sets this field separator only for `file2`.